# gnome-boxes crashes on startup after cancelling clone of a VM by closing the program

Tags: gnome-boxes

I know, there's a [similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/682688/how-to-delete-gnome-boxes-machine-from-bash) with the problem manifesting in a similar way but using `virsh` didn't work for me, it refused to delete the problematic VM.

I tried deleting all the configs to stop gnome-boxes from trying to load a faulty VM list but it didn't work. I deleted everything named `gnome-boxes*` in my home directory and `apt purge`ing it then reinstalling, the problem persisted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by deleting `$HOME/.config/libvirt`. I didn't notice any negative side effects with that (although it's probably better to delete/edit the problematic file therein, but I don't know which one) and now `gnome-boxes` works again flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced the issue of gnome-boxes crashing at launch after an interrupted cloning of a virtual machine.

What worked for me on Ubuntu 22.04

Install virsh

```
sudo apt install libvirt-clients
```

List the machines

```
virsh -c qemu:///session list --all
```

Undefine the problematic machine

```
virsh -c qemu:///session undefine <machine-name-here>
```

Comment: As I wrote in the question, using `virsh` didn't work for me because it refused to undefine the VM, I have found that exact solution several times already out there.